# Как автоматически подстроить scrollView под размер контента?

Tags: ios, objective-c, content, scrollview

В ViewController есть картинка и текст. Высота всего контента зависит от размера текста. Как автоматически подстроить scrollView под меняющийся размер контента?

Comment: вам надо при изменении содержания текста менять contentSize скролл вью?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Да. Автоматически. Сейчас я подстраиваю высоту вью под каждый новый размер контента.

Comment: в таком случае, вряд ли вы найдете что-то лучше. при изменении текста высчитать новый размер контента и присвоить его. все

Comment: Жаль. Уж очень много однообразной работы получается.

Comment: да нет вроде - в 3 строки кода должны уложиться.

Comment: Хотя да, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел у себя метод, который добавляет текст в `UITextView` и продлевает его (contentSize не frame). Может поможет.

```
- (void)injectMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    NSString *text = self.callbacksView.text; // callbacksView это UITextView
    text = [text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@", message];
    self.callbacksView.text = text;
    CGSize size = [self.callbacksView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.callbacksView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    self.callbacksView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.callbacksView.contentSize.width, size.height);
    [self.callbacksView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.callbacksView.contentSize.height - self.callbacksView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    // последняя строка скроллит контент вниз таким образом,
    // чтобы только что добавленная строка оказалась видна в самом низу фрейма.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я расскажу о самом простом, есть еще вариант программно, но я про InterfaceBuilder способ:

1. Открываешь Interface Builder и выбираещь свой ScrollView
2. Нажимаешь на кнопку Pin
3. Указываешь необходимые отступы от всех остальных "границ"
4. Незабываем нажать блокировку
5. Добавляем констрейны и ...

Все, наслаждаемся. Там таким образом многое что можно Автоматически регулировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это понятно. 
Во вью размер контента меняется по нажатию кнопки. Что конкретно мне нужно сделать, чтобы scrollView автоматически продлился?

Comment: и? не совсем понятно. Если ты во всей вью закрепишь все объекты, то с изменением размера окна, они автоматически скорректируются. просто надо закреплять сразу все и четко привязывать к границам окна.

Comment: можно так же значения Констрейнов программно менять при нажатии кнопки, если это надо.

Comment: Вот хороший туториал: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints

Comment: Хорошо.Попробую

Comment: со скролл вью и констрейнтами есть проблема - он перестает скролиться если его закреплять констрейнтами. вот как это можно обойти https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html